# Exclude some fields in findAll Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I use this code for getting all users in the database

```
$users= $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:Users')
        ->findAll();
        return $this->render('livre/users.html.twig',array(
            'users' => $users,
        ));
```

But me I want get only some fields sush as `name`,`email` and hide fields like `password`..
Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered just not rendering the password in the view?

Comment: Sorry I don't understood

Answer (score 6):

You can do it by this way:

1/ Create a specific method in the UserRepository class:

```
public function findByNameAndEmail()
{
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->select('u.name, u.email') // where name & email are properties of your User entity
    ;

    return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

2/ And, call it in your controller:

```
public function someAction()    
{
    $users = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Users')->findByNameAndEmail();

    return $this->render('livre/users.html.twig',array(
        'users' => $users,
    ));
}
```

Comment: if for any reason you need objects and not just an array result have a look at PARTIAL syntax (which is partly hydrating your object): http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/partial-objects.html